# Catch crashes in C

Tags: c, error-handling

I am currently developping a program in C that has to run without failure, because it has to run 24/7. However, due to safety reasons (it has control over high voltages), I would like it to run a function that turns off some stuff anytime it does crash. I would like to do this because I want to ensure that whenever something goes wrong, things are turned off.

Is there any way to develop a function as a 'cleanup', that runs anytime the code crashes? I tried looking for others with similar problems but I am having trouble finding them.

I hope someone has a solution for my problem!

Kind regards,
Tim

Comment: Can you maybe add some of your current code?

Comment: You would fork a process, and call [`waitpid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid), to wait for the exit status.

Comment: you might wanna have a look at [this](http://www.slideshare.net/GiorgiMoniava/introduction-to-undefined-behavior-in-c-and-c), at least, if you want program that has to run without failure.

Comment: So what happens when the operating system crashes?

Comment: @arc_lupus How is that exactly relevant? I just want it to run a specific line of code whenever it crashes. The code itself seems irrelevant to me in that case.

Comment: @self Thanks! I will have a look into that.

Comment: There is no concept of "crash" in C, only "undefined behaviour" (google this). On which platform is your code running?

Comment: You can use OS-specific functions like `sigaction()` to set up handlers for the signals that are sent to crash a process. But the problem is that whatever caused the crash may have corrupted memory in such a way that you can't depend on being able to do anything useful at that time.

Comment: So the code that tries to clean up could actually end up doing more damage.

Comment: 1) If that potentially dangerous for humans or equipment, that better be a bare-metal embedded system, i.e. a MCU. If not, use an MCU in-between which controls the critical I/O. On any halfway modern MCU, there should be proper features to support failsafe operation. But that is too broad for this site.

Comment: @Timmeh: The major problem is no language (sic!) can guarantee it will behave in a defined way **under all conditions**. The more complexity you add, the more places of failure you have. Anyway, most MCUs have measures to account for this. Check your platform and learn about failsafe software.

Comment: With high voltages, you also haved to deal with hardware-faults, btw. EMC is a major problem in such systems. The software has to catch problems induced by the hardware.

Comment: or : use an RTOS, RT-programming and a "managed" / "virtualized" or even "interpreted" language which offers runtime checks and guarantees about behaviour. Doing these kinds of tasks with languages like C is **very** hard and probably too much effort *unless* you're prepared to write ASM or use OS-specific API - it usually involves buying entire, proprietary build-systems and customizing your kernel *(if you happen to use Linux)*. You might want to start with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) ... it'll assist you in your first steps